# Dragon Breath (Acid) vs a Ship's Hull?

Tags: spells, vehicles

If a party was Water Breathing and under a ship at night, could they use Dragon Breath (Acid) to make a hole in the hull of a ship?

Comment: Welcome! Which RPG game/system/edition is this question about? You can [edit] in the corresponding tag, such as [dnd-5e] or [dungeon-world] or you can also comment here if you are unsure and we can help figure things out.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. As Sdjz said, we need to know the RPG system/edition you're asking about in order to answer the question. Once you clarify, we can reopen it.